# Loading Some things in SplashActivty in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I have a class named Initializer which checks for Internet connection, load open feint and google analytics and calls some notification adds. This is a simple class. Now I want it to replace it with a splash screen. Can any one help me that how can I add the splash screen functionality and Initialize all these things at the same time while the screen is splashing in AndEngine? I know how to add a simple splash screen but dont know how to Initialize other things with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an AsyncTask. Essentially, this creates a background thread that can do longer tasks without blocking the UI thread.